# Python script to get all private repos from an org/user

Tags: python, api, github

I'm on a mac and I'm trying to run a python script to get all the private repos from my organization/employees. Here's what I have so far:

```
import github3

gh = github3.login("username", "personal_access_taken")
org = gh.organization("org_name")
repos = list(org.iter_repos(type="private"))

print(repos)
```

Just an FYI, I'm new to python and API. Just started a few hours ago so I'm a complete newbie to this. I ran it and get back:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "repo.py", line 4, in <module>
    org = gh.organization("org_name")
  File "/Users/user/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/github3/github.py", line 1566, in organization
    json = self._json(self._get(url), 200)
  File "/Users/user/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/github3/models.py", line 156, in _json
    raise exceptions.error_for(response)
github3.exceptions.NotFoundError: 404 Not Found`

What should I change to my script to make it work? Also, if I need to change to an employee would i replace `org = gh.organization("org_name")` with `user = gh.user("employee_name)`?

Comment: Could you provide the full text of the error?

Comment: Edited post with error

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works for me.

Make sure that you entered the correct organization name and that your user has access to this organization:

```py
org = gh.organization("org_name")
```

You also should replace deprecated `iter_repos()` to [repositories()](https://github3.readthedocs.io/en/master/api-reference/orgs.html#github3.orgs.ShortTeam.repositories) method:

```py
repos = list(org.repositories())
```

Comment: when i run it for user and replace "org" with "user", I get "AttributeError: iter_repos". What should i replace "iter_repos" with when running for user?

Comment: Wouldn't it be user.repositories? Since i'm replacing "org" with "user"? I still hit "AttributeError: repositories"

Comment: If you want to list user repositories, try this: `user_repos = list(gh.repositories())`

Comment: Aha it worked! Thank you. Is there a way to have the script list just the repo names? This is the result from the script: [testchrishahahn/Test-1]>, <ShortRepository [testchrishahahn/Test-1-Public]>, <ShortRepository [testchrishahahn/Test-Repo]>]

Comment: Great! Use `full_name` field as described in github3 API reference: https://github3.readthedocs.io/en/master/api-reference/repos.html#github3.repos.repo.ShortRepository.full_name

Comment: Github API docs states `full_name` is by default. It's not a big deal. Last thing, what do i add to my `print` function to create a new line for every repo pulled? I tried `sep='\n'`, but still outputs it all in one line

Comment: `print()` function by default ends with newline. How do you print your repos? I suppose that you print a list of repos, am I right? If so, iterate over list elements in `for` loop and print them out one at a time. Or consider pretty printer module for a list object: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html

Comment: I could kiss you right now.... <3 Thank you! Not necessary, but the final output has `ShortRepository` in all of the repos. Is that removable through the api call? Or that can't be altered?

Comment: Just print `full_name` field for ShortRepository objects: `for r in repos: print(r.full_name)`